# creating a database with same credentials

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a front application, where i can jump in to that database. now i want to create a database for the server because one server can have many databases, so if i am in that selected database called as `abc`, i can go ahead and create a another databse `babyabc`, but want that this `babyabc` should have all permissions and login information of the parent abc database.

is it possible to do in sql server, if yes how can i do it

for creating a database, i can do always as:

```
create database babyabc
```

Answer (score 0):

Database Permissions are set at the database level. If you have two similar databases, you need to create the appropriate `USER`, `ROLE`s, etc in both of them.

If you have some which are needed on every database, and don't have permissions specific to User  objects (which differ), you can create and set the permissions in the `model` database. Then any databases created *after* you've made those changes to the `model` database will have those permissions.

For example, you might have an AD group that you automatically want to be on the database, and have the `db_datareader` role. So you would do:

```sql
USE model;
GO

CREATE USER [StackOverflow\RegisteredUsers];
GO

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [StackOverflow\RegisteredUsers];
GO
```

Then, if you create a new database, that user will be in the new database, and have the `db_datareader` role.

Comment: what i am saying i am already in one server and one server can have multiple databases, and for a new database, i want that whatever database i am in, creating new database will have same permissions of the database i am already in, like inhering the permissions

Comment: That isn't how databases work, @SignUp . You don't create a database inside another.